# Setup email address forwarding on Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, smtp

NB:  This server has SMTP installed, Exchange is not available to be installed on this box.

I'd like to set up a server to accept email for one domain.  e.g. emails sent to 12345@acceptdomain.com and then reroute these emails to a different domain address, say 12345@reroutedomain.com.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the question 4 line below yours:
[How do I set up SMTP on Windows Server 2003 to forward all emails to a given address?](https://serverfault.com/questions/24618/how-do-i-set-up-smtp-on-windows-server-2003-to-forward-all-emails-to-a-given-addr)

Comment: That question has an answer, but writing an exchange event sync is not easy!